# Sockets: Simulate multiple clients in python using one machine/NIC

Tags: python, sockets, client-side

I am trying to write a python program that will spawn multiple clients to speak to one server on the network.  My question is what do I need to do to simulate different IP addresses for each client?

I am using MAC OSX Lion right now with Python 2.6.

I have already developed the server side that can accept multiple sockets.  I want to avoid having a machine for each client.  Any tips/hints for a newbie would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want different IP addresses? You can connect multiple clients from the same IP to a socket.

Comment: @ms4py Perhaps he's testing something that relies specifically on differing IP addresses and not just the `(ip, port)` combo.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question, it still appears in google...

As already mentioned, basically it will take the IP the connection is received from and assigns the next available port... So with a standard socket.. you will end up with a bunch of connections from the same IP with varying ports.

Personally to me its easier to create a client script that will generate the amount of clients you need (i'm using 1000+ clients from a single python script)..

Once you have the clients generated, have the script generate a IP for each of the clients.. If your handling your connection objects correctly.. You can always refer back to which client you want..

So in the end, you have all the clients coming from the same machine or another on the network but you simply have variable with a random/generated IP address which you can test with.. It takes only a few lines to use the generated IP address as a reference to your socket object.

---

If you are wanting to work with something IP specific like only allow a connection from a particular subnet.. Simply generate the fake IP address at the time of the connection and use it as if it was the real one.

If you are just wanting to have multiple clients, no need to generate a IP address at all as everything is a different port.

---

Extract for example purpose:

```
for i in xrange(1, self.iCount + 1):
    if len(self.objClients) >= self.iCount:
        break

    #Generate a uid ... sID = xxxxxx+i
    if sID not in self.objClients:
        oPosData = []
        self.objClients[i] = {"id":sID, "current":0, "connected":True}

for oT in self.objClients:
    try:
        self.objClients[oT]['socket'] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.objClients[oT]['socket'].connect((self.ServerIP, self.ServerPort))
        self.objClients[oT]['timer'] = time.time() + randint(0, 10)
```

Comment: This doesn't really help. May be you should give your code here so its easier.

Comment: can you share your code to create multiple clients?

Comment: Its not hard to loop the creation of a client and keep them in a collection / dict.

Comment: I love how people down vote without comment, well just going to assume its from a person who wanted me to write their code for them.

Answer (score -2):

http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection

> If supplied, source_address must be a 2-tuple `(host, port)` for the socket to bind to as its source address before connecting.

I think that should do it.

Comment: Don't assume, test your answers. This only works for physical available IPs or it will raise `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`.

Comment: @ms4py Huh, so it utilizes `socket.bind()` underneath everything, and that only accepts valid local addresses (depending on the underlying implementation, at least)... makes sense, all things considered, as binding a socket to an address that isn't local means you'll never get anything back to it as the data the server sends back will be directed to that non-local IP address, so the creators likely assumed that would be undesirable behavior, but it seems like something that should be noted in the documentation.